# phpmyadmin is saving â€™ to mysql database instead of ' from cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am saving to the database from cakephp to mysql. When I view the data with phpmyadmin, `"driver's"` is saved as `"driverâ€™s". Is there a way to save these entries as normal escape characters? I thought cake would take care of these before they even got to the database. Also, If I do have to keep them this way, how do I unescape them when I pull them back out of the database?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `start` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `stop` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `completed` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `fc_module_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fc_section_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `selections` text character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1035 ;
```

the "selections" column is the one that is giving me trouble. It wasn't always set to latin1_bin that is just the latest charset that I tried after I tried utf8_bin. But really I was just making guesses at the charset.

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: See this question and answer for a potential solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662093/cakephp-mysql-insert-utf-8

Comment: My guess is that the tool you are using (phpmyadmin) to validate that the data is saved correctly is using latin1 encoding. Change this to utf8 and the data will be rendered in phpmyadmin okay.

Comment: @stealthyninja added `'encoding' => 'utf8'` to the `app/config/database.php` array and that solved the problem. Thank you. If you put it as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Jim Joyce -- Cool; I've [added it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213689/phpmyadmin-is-saving-a-to-mysql-database-instead-of-from-cakephp/8214515#8214515) now. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the

```
'encoding' => 'utf8',
```

setting for your database in `app/config/database.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the character is not being saved well, it's that your phpmyadmin is probably displaying it in another encoding (probably latin1) set than that it's being saved as.

You shouldn't have a problem fetching the character in the correct encoding.

It probably isn't a real single quote as well, as that should show up nicely in both latin1 and utf-8 encoding.

After changing your phpmyadmin to no longer display it in latin1 (because your character is not latin1), also update your table to utf-8. Otherwise, you might get into trouble: your column assumes your text is latin1 now (character set latin1 collate latin1_bin), but it contains utf-8 data.